# Как получить промежуточные значения дат?

Tags: javascript

Делаю компонент datepicker, в нем есть range с значениями: startDate и endDate. Как получить промежуточные даты?

**пример**

startDate = 21.02.2018, endDate = 25.02.2018

Необходимо получить 22.02.2018, 23.02.2018 и 24.02.2018

Answer (score 1):

```js
var startDate = new Date(2018, 1, 21);
var endDate = new Date(2018, 1, 25);

var currentDate = startDate;
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
while (currentDate < endDate) {
  console.log(currentDate.toLocaleDateString());
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Ваш код неккоректно работает. Выводит 21,22,23 число, а нужно 22,23,24.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Скорость наверное будет невысокой, зато</del> надежно и более-менее читаемо:

```js
// возвращает массив Date, значения которых не содержат время, и находятся между датами dFrom и dTo
function getDatesBetween(dFrom, dTo) {
  let result  = [], 
      toDateN = dTo, 
      bufDate = dFrom, 
      incBufDate = () => bufDate.setDate(bufDate.getDate() + 1); 
  toDateN.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  toDateN = +toDateN; 
  bufDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  for (incBufDate(); +bufDate < toDateN; incBufDate())
    result.push(new Date(bufDate.getTime())); 
  return result;
}

let dates = getDatesBetween(new Date('2018-02-21'), new Date('2018-02-25')); 
dates.forEach(d => console.log(d.toLocaleDateString()));
```

[Тест на JSperf](https://jsperf.com/a-820513-288409).